# Last scene of taxi driver

Tags: plot-explanation, taxi-driver

In the last scene of *Taxi Driver*, we see Travis (Robert de Niro) doing a strange and rapid movement with his eyes: what does it mean?

I can't find a clip, sorry.

**EDIT**

I am referring to the last seconds of the movie, when Travis catches his glance in the rear-view mirror, like @inkwarp wrote.

Comment: Are you referring to him catching his glance in his rear-view mirror?
If so, I would have thought that was obvious, that he cannot see himself as he really is. that's how it seems to me. The guy is quite insane by that point, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the commentary track on the laserdisc, Scorsese acknowledges that the final scene of Bickle (DeNiro) glancing at an unseen object indicates that he is like a ticking timebomb, and that at any moment he can fall back into a character full of rage and recklessness.

The DVD commentary with writer Paul Schrader speaks about Bickle not being "cured" at the end of the movie, and that "Next time he won't be the hero".

So, it's safe to say that the ending indicates that Bickle is still a bit psychotic and unstable.